# iOS drawing over UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, drawing

I need to draw over an image graffiti style, as below.  My problem is that I need to have the capability to erase the lines I've drawn without erasing sections of the UIImage.  At the moment I'm considering using one image for the background image and another image, with a transparent background, for the graffiti drawing, then combining the two once the drawing is complete.  Is there a better way?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    //Get drawing context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Create drawing layer if required
    if(drawingLayer == nil)
    {
        drawingLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
        CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(drawingLayer);
        CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
        self.viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.width);

        NSLog(@"%f %f",self.viewRect.size.width,self.viewRect.size.width);
    }

    //Draw paths from array
    int arrayCount = [pathArray count];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        path = [pathArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIBezierPath *bezierPath = path.bezierPath;
        CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(drawingLayer);
        CGContextAddPath(layerContext, bezierPath.CGPath);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, path.width);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, path.color.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineCap(layerContext, kCGLineCapRound);

        if(activeColor == 4)
        {
            CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext, kCGBlendModeClear);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext, kCGBlendModeNormal);
        }

        CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);
    }

    if (loadedImage == NO)
    {
        loadedImage = YES;
    CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(drawingLayer);
    CGContextSaveGState(layerContext);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (self.viewRect.size);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(layerContext, 0, self.viewRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(layerContext, self.viewRect, self.image.CGImage);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGContextRestoreGState(layerContext);
    }

    [pathArray removeAllObjects];

    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.viewRect, drawingLayer);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Set the image in UIImageView and use a normal UIView on top of the image view for drawing/erasing etc. On save, just update the image with drawn contents, reset it in image view and clear drawing on UIView.